# Why is the username still displayed even when it's been deleted using 'userdel'

Tags: users, user-management, adduser

I added a user with the `adduser` command and then deleted it with`userdel`, but the username is still displayed in the home directory and in the ***switch account*** section.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, `userdel` only deletes the user from `/etc/passwd`. To remove their home directory too, you pass the `-r` or `--remove` flag.

Once the user has been removed using `userdel`, you cannot retrospectively run `userdel -r user` to remove the home directory; instead you need to delete the user's home directory yourself, for example by running

```
sudo rm -r /home/user
```

replacing *`user`* with the username you want to remove.

If there is an entry for the user in `/var/mail`, or whatever directory is defined for `MAIL_DIR` in `/etc/login.defs` (run `grep MAIL_DIR /etc/login.defs` to check), you can delete that too.

Deleting the home directory should fix the *switch account* menu too, but I couldn't reproduce your issue on my Ubuntu MATE system. Perhaps rebooting after removing the user's home directory is also needed for you.

See also the more flexible tool [`deluser`](http://man.he.net/man8/deluser).